# PHP "??" operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

Easy question. Does exist something like php's `??` in javascript?

In php you can do `condition ?? statement2`

which is the same as `condition? condition : statement2`.

Is there something like that in javascript?

Comment: @JordanRunning similar answer, but not directly comparing PHP to JS

Comment: Good. `||` worked. Thanks

Comment: @ps2goat In PHP `??` is called the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). The linked question is "Null coalescing operator Javascript." It's literally the same question, and the accepted answer there answers OP's question exactly.

Comment: True, but people don't always know the official names of things, so that question may not show up in their search.

Comment: @ps2goat is right, That is why I asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the logical or operator (`||`)

```js
console.log("true value" || "other")
console.log(false || "other")
```

This works because ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)):

> `expr1 || expr2` Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`

Answer (score 0):

So, if condition is false, go with statement2.

That's as simple as `condition || statement2`

If condition is truthy, if will be selected. If not, statement2 will be evaluated.